# Clear Form Button is not working correctly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Created a master.page and added several content pages. Imported the code from previous webform into one of my content pages. Now the clear button is not working correctly. It will not clear the textboxes or checkboxes. greatly appreciate any help. The form worked perfectly as a standalone page.

vb code:
    Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4 As Double
    Dim Opt1, Opt2, Opt3, Opt4 As Double
    Dim BaseTotal, OptionTotal, GrandTotal, Tax As Double
    Num1 = Val(TextBox1.Text) * 1500
    Num2 = Val(TextBox2.Text) * 70
    Num3 = Val(TextBox3.Text) * 90
    Num4 = Val(TextBox4.Text) * 130

    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        Opt1 = 175
    End If

    If CheckBox2.Checked Then
        Opt2 = 400
    End If

    If CheckBox3.Checked Then
        Opt3 = 100
    End If

    If CheckBox4.Checked Then
        Opt4 = 200
    End If

    ' sum of checkboxes
    OptionTotal = Opt1 + Opt2 + Opt3 + Opt4

    'total base options
    BaseTotal = Num1 + Num2 + Num3 + Num4

    ' Tax calculation
    Tax = (OptionTotal + BaseTotal) * 0.095

    GrandTotal = (BaseTotal + OptionTotal + Tax)
    'output to text boxes
    TextBox5.Text = FormatNumber(BaseTotal, 2)
    TextBox6.Text = FormatNumber(OptionTotal, 2)
    TextBox7.Text = FormatNumber(Tax, 2)
    TextBox8.Text = FormatNumber(GrandTotal, 2)
End Sub

For Each ctrl As Control In form1.Controls
        If ctrl.[GetType]() = GetType(TextBox) Then
            DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox).Text = String.Empty
        ElseIf ctrl.[GetType]() = GetType(CheckBox) Then
            DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked = False
        End If
    Next
```

***************If I use the following code of course it works, however it would be tedious if there were numerous controls on the page.

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox4.Text = ""
    TextBox5.Text = ""
    TextBox6.Text = ""
    TextBox7.Text = ""
    TextBox8.Text = ""
    CheckBox1.Checked = False
    CheckBox2.Checked = False
    CheckBox3.Checked = False
    CheckBox4.Checked = False
End Sub
```

---

Comment: What is 'form1' in this context? Should that be Me.Controls?

Comment: Form1 was the form created on the original website page that I copied over to the content page within the master.page project.